# php if string contains any character from an array

Tags: php, arrays, special-characters

I have an xml document that gets loaded onto a page.  Sometimes there are specific characters that cannot be parsed and shows this symbol in place of what should be there:  `â€“`

Sometimes the character varies from a hyphen, to an apostrophe, to even a double quote.

What I'd like to do is, create an array:

`$invalidCharacters = array(" – ", "’", "&");`

and if the string contains any of those characters, replace them with their HTML/ASCII equivalent. like this: `" &ndash; "`, `"&#39;"`, and `&amp;`.

I know that I can do a `str_replace()` on some items, but, is there a simple way to have it go trough a loop and look for the specific characters, replacing each as it goes?

Comment: str_replace with arrays just performs all the replacements sequentially.

Comment: Getting `â€“` sounds more like a character set issue than anything, e.g. dumping utf8 text into an iso8859 environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `htmlspecialchars` should work for you.

http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php

Comment: So, wait... all I would have to do is something like this? `$MyString = htmlspecialchars($myotherstring);`  And that's it??

Comment: Yes, you could add a flag for XML. It would look like `$MyString = htmlspecialchars($myotherstring, ENT_XML1);`